# Implementing cosine_decay with LearningRateScheduler

Tags: keras

I want to use `LearningRateScheduler` to implment the cosine decay learning rate, and whenever I implement the following code it gave the error below:

> ValueError: The output of the "schedule" function should be float.

```
class CosineDecreaseX(object):
    def __init__(self,  decay_steps , baseLR):
      self.decay_steps = decay_steps
      self.baseLR = baseLR

   def lr_func(self, epoch):
      LR = tf.compat.v1.train.cosine_decay(learning_rate=self.baseLR,global_step= epoch,decay_steps= self.decay_steps)
      return LR

 decay = CosineDecrease( decay_steps=1000 ,  baseLR= 0.0001)
 reduce_lr = tf.compat.v1.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(decay.lr_func, verbose=1)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?